# How to know index of current Object with name

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array called poemcollection

```
poemcollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"twinkle_twinkle" ofType:@"mp3"],
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"baa_baa_black_sheep" ofType:@"mp3"],
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"johny_johny" ofType:@"mp3"],
```

on button click
I want to know which object is playing currently from this array and index of this object.
I want to print in log this both name and index of current file playing on player

Comment: NSString *mediaFileName = [[self.player.url absoluteString] lastPathComponent];

Comment: i have tried this code fro getting name of current mp3.it works but how i know the index of this current mp3 from poemcollection array?

Comment: Why don't you just loop through your array and compare the name of the file with the file name in the path for each array object ? If there's a match you got your index.

Answer (score 0):

```
[poemcollection indexOfObject:YOUR_CURRENT_PLAYING_OBJECT];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
-(void)printCurrentlyPlaying
{

    NSString *mediaFileName = [[self.player.url absoluteString] lastPathComponent];

    BOOL found = NO;

    int poemIndex = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < poemcollection.count && !found; i++)
    {
        NSString *filePath = poemcollection[i];

        NSString *fileName = [filePath lastPathComponent];

        if([fileName isEqualToString:mediaFileName])
        {
            found = YES;
            poemIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if(found)
    {
        NSLog(@"Currently playing: %@, track number: %d", mediaFileName, poemIndex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a mapping dictionary for the media name, e.g -

```
    poemCollection = @[ @{"Twinkle twinkle": [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"twinkle_twinkle" ofType:@"mp3"]},
                  @{@"Baa baa black sheep": [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"baa_baa_black_sheep" ofType:@"mp3"]},
                  @{"Johny Johny": [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"johny_johny" ofType:@"mp3"]}];

//And read the title like below :
NSString *title = [poemCollection[index] allKeys][0]
NSString *musicFile = [poemCollection[index] allValues][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to get current file name and object.

```
NSString *currentFile = [[self.player.url absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
[poemcollection indexOfObject:currentFile];
```